# Using PHP (and maybe AJAX?) with jQTouch

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, ajax, jqtouch

I am having some difficulty using PHP with jQTouch.
 I am fairly 
confident with JavaScript however my PHP skills are little to none.
 
I am creating an application for my final year project at University 
what displays football rumours posted by different users. 
My problem 
is as follows: 
I have one screen that displays each individual rumour, using a while 
loop in PHP I am able to get each rumour from the database and display 
them correctly. However I want to be able to click on one rumour which 
then displays this rumour in a different screen, along with options to 
reply/share etc. However I do not know how to tell which rumour has 
been clicked on. 

Snippets of my code: 
All rumours page:

```
    <?php 
        $q1 = "SELECT * FROM tblrumours;"; 
        $r1 = mysql_query($q1); 
        while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1) ){ 
?> 
    <a class="rumourTag submit" id="<?php echo $row1['rumourID']; ?>"> 
            <div class='oneRumour'> 
            <div class='standardBubble'> 
                    <p> 
                    <?php 
                            $userID = $row1['userID']; 
                            $q2 = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE userID = $userID;"; 
                            $r2 = mysql_query($q2); 
                            while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2) ){ 
                                    $username = $row2['username']; 
                                    $teamID = $row2['teamID']; 
                            } 
                            $q5 = "SELECT * FROM tblteams WHERE teamID = $teamID;"; 
                            $r5 = mysql_query($q5); 
                            while( $row5 = mysql_fetch_array($r5) ){ 
                                    echo "<img src='img/".$row5['teamPicture']."' alt='' 
    class='teamImg' />"; 
                            } 
                    ?> 
                    <span class='username'> 
                    <?php 
                            echo $username; 
                    ?> 
                    </span> 
                    <br/> 
                    <span class='rumourMsg'><?php echo $row1['rumourText']; ?></ 
    span> 
            </p> 
        </div>
    </a>
```

SINGLE RUMOURS PAGE:

```
<?php 
       $q1 = "SELECT * FROM tblrumours WHERE rumourID = 1;"; /* NEED 
TO SELECT WHERE RUMOUR ID IS THE ONE THAT IS CLICKED */ 
        $r1 = mysql_query($q1); 
        while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1) ){ 
?>..........
```

I have tried using Session variables, storing the ID's in an array, 
creating a separate php file for the single rumour page, and all to no 
avail. I am guessing I have to use AJAX in some way, but I have no 
idea where to even begin. Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to click on a rumour to see more details about it, you could always output in the HTML a unique value used to reference that rumour in the DB.

e.g. have `<span class='rumourMsg' id='rumourName'>` where rumourName is a unique value stored in your database to reference that rumour. Then when a user clicks to see more details, you can make a request to the PHP page with that value and return the content.

e.g. `rumourDetails?rumourName=uniqueRumourName`

(make sure to escape all your data properly to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with it being in jQTouch since all pages are stored on one index.php file and are referenced using different div ID's, so there is no actual refresh when switching between views. This is why I think I have to incorporate AJAX some how? - Sorry if I've misunderstood though.